# Why specifying a lvalue reference for *this on a member function is different from not specifying anything?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    void f() { cout << "A::f" << endl; }
    void f() const { cout << "A::f const" << endl; }
};

struct B {
    void f() & { cout << "B::f &" << endl; }
    void f() const & { cout << "B::f const &" << endl; }
};

A getA() { return A{}; }
B getB() { return B{}; }

int main() {
    getA().f();
    getB().f();
}
```

which prints

```
A::f
B::f const &
```

For `B`, the const overload gets selected, not the non-const one. I guess this means that specifying a lvalue ref qualifier for *this is different from not specifying anything at all. Why is that? Does the "implicit this argument" change type and the const overload now becomes a better candidate in overload resolution?

Comment: `B::f` gets called on a `B &&`. Since you cannot convert an rvalue reference to an lvalue reference (unless you are visual studio), you cannot call `B::f &`. I don't know if `A::f` is the same as `A::f &&`.

Comment: @nwp it's not, `A::f() &&` can _only_ be called on rvalues.

Comment: The trick here is that ref-qualifier `const &` can bind to a rvalue!  (making it fairly useless)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case:

```
struct A {
    void f() { cout << "A::f" << endl; }
    void f() const { cout << "A::f const" << endl; }
};

getA().f();
```

Both overloads are viable for `f`, but the non-const one is preferred because it requires no conversion.

But in this case:

```
struct B {
    void f() & { cout << "B::f &" << endl; }
    void f() const & { cout << "B::f const &" << endl; }
};

getB().f();
```

The first overload requires `this` to be an lvalue. But in `getB().f()`, the result of `getB()` is a prvalue, which can't bind to a non-const lvalue. So this overload is not viable and not selected.

The second overload however requires `this` to be a const lvalue, which a prvalue can bind to: this overload is viable and selected by the compiler.

Comment: I totally understand that part, but about *not* specifying reference qualifiers on `f()`? Basically the entire point is now that saying that `&` is equivalent to not having a ref qualifier is false.

Comment: Of course adding a ref-qualifier is different to not having a ref-qualifier at all, otherwise what would be the point of the feature?! What gave you the idea that "`&` is equivalent to not having a ref qualifier" might be true in the first place?

Comment: My point was that instead they should be treated equally for the purposes of overload resolution. But now after rereading the Standard for the 24th time I think I've got where my reasoning was in mistake. I'll post an answer for reference. Thanks for making me rethink again.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: that you can now overload also on lvalue/rvalue.

Comment: @peppe, yes, but a `&` qualifier restricts to lvalues, whereas no qualifier doesn't restrict at all. Having some restriction is obviously not the same as having no restriction!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: see below. I think I was confused by the Standard wording.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, the sentence that totally misled me is in `[over.match.funcs]`, §13.3.1/4 of N3337:

> 4. For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> — **“lvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared without a ref-qualifier or with the & ref-qualifier**
>
> — “rvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared with the && ref-qualifier

(emphasis mine).

So I was getting kind of crazy about why there was a difference in the output. Without or with a `&` ref qualifier should be the same according to here, right?

Well, the reason is an additional rule sneaked in afterwards in §13.3.1/5

> For non-static member functions declared without a ref-qualifier, an additional rule applies:
>
> — even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, an rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long as in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter.

Which basically triggers the non-const rvalue to non-const lvalue conversion and makes **all the difference** in the example above. D'uh.

Comment: Usually, if I'm confused about how some C++11/14 feature works, I check the paper that proposed the feature, which has a wording section that shows all the changes made to the standard, and often either the rationale behind the proposal or a pointer to an earlier version that contains the rationale. In this case, it would be [N2439](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm). The GCC folks have a handy list for all [C++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) and [C++14](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) features that link to the corresponding paper.